# Send a file to a sever periodically with AlarmManager

Tags: android

I want my app send a log file, to a server. I wrote a code, which gathers all info from Log. Then I want to send it at 22.00 PM to a server. 
I can upload the file but pressing a button. But I want it do do by some deamon(AlarmManager)
How should I do that? What if there is no internet connection at this specific time? Is there any examples of such implementation?

And where I should create my alarm? While I create it in onCreate method it will create new alram every time onCreate method is called. I want it to be called only once

Thanks.

Comment: see this page http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use example from here:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

it is using AlarmManager which triggers broadcast that starts IntentService which exeuctes with wakelock. So it will work also in background. To check if internet connection is present, use below code :

```
   NetworkInfo networkInfo = getConnectivityManager().getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null) {
      return networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    }
```

inside your IntentService.

Comment: where I should create my alarm? While I create it in onCreate method it will create new alram every time onCreate method is called. I want it to be called only once.

Comment: @alex inside `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, its all in the link I have provided.